# How to use my application in context menu?

Tags: windows, path, registry, contextmenu

I know, that I can write "firefox.exe" in registry command, but when I write my application like "myapp.exe" it doesn't work. If I use full path "C:...\myapp.exe" it works, but application can be installed anywhere else, so how to write short command?

Also, in run utilite when I write myapp.exe it can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tell windows to run a program and you don't specify the full path, it looks at the PATH variable, which contains just a string of directories separated by ";" and sees if it finds the program there. There is a more detailed explanation of it on https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them.